# Are the elements created by numpy.repeat() views of the original numpy.array or unique elements?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D array that I like to repeat 4 times.

**Achieved via a mixture of Numpy and Python methods:**

```
>>> z = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> z
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> z2 = []

>>> for i in range(4):
    z2.append(z)

    
>>> z2
[array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]]), array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]]), array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]]), array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])]
>>> z2 = np.array(z2)
>>> z2
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]]])
```

**Achieved via Pure NumPy:**

```
>>> z2 = np.repeat(z[np.newaxis,...], 4, axis=0)
>>> z2
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]]])
```

Are the elements created by `numpy.repeat()` views of the original `numpy.array()` or unique elements?

If the latter, is there an equivalent NumPy functions that can create views of the original array the same way as `numpy.repeat()`?

I think such an ability can help reduce the buffer space of `z2` in the event size of `z` is large and when there are many repeats of `z` involved.

**A follow-up on one of @FrankYellin answer:**

```
>>> z = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> z
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> z2 = np.repeat(z[np.newaxis,...], 1_000_000_000, axis=0)
>>> z2.nbytes
72000000000
>>> y2 = np.broadcast_to(z, (1_000_000_000, 3, 3))
>>> y2.nbytes
72000000000
```

The nbytes from using `np.broadcast_to()` is the same as `np.repeat()`. This is surprising given that the former returns a readonly view on the original `z` array with the given shape. Having said this, I did notice that `np.broadcast_to()` created the `y2` array instantaneously, while the creation of `z2` via `np.repeat()` took abt 40 seconds to complete. Hence,`np.broadcast_to()` yielded significantly faster performance.

Comment: Would a broadcastable (1,3,3) shape be just as useful?

Comment: `np.repeat(z[np.newaxis,...], 4, axis=0).flags.owndata` will tell you the answer.

Comment: @MechanicPig `z2.flags.owndata` returns `True` while `y2.flags.owndata` returns `False`. All the more it seems strange to me that their `nbytes` value are identical.

Comment: In fact, the repeated arrays obtained by broadcasting are likely to come from the reference of the original array, that is to say, there is no array copy during broadcasting.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a writable version, it is doable, but it's really ugly.

If you want a read-only version, `np.broadcast_to(z, (4, 3, 3))` should be all you need.

Now the ugly writable version.  Be careful.  You can corrupt memory if you mess the arguments up.

```
> z.shape
(3, 3)
> z.strides
(24, 8)
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
z2 = as_strided(z, shape=(4, 3, 3), strides=(0, 24, 8))
```

and you end up with:

```
>>> z2[1, 1, 1]
4
>>> z2[1, 1, 1] = 100
>>> z2[2, 1, 1]
100
>>>
```

You are using strides to say that I want to create a second array overlayed on top of the first array.  You set its new shape, and you prefix 0 to the previous stride, indicating that the first dimension has no effect on the data you want.

Make sure you understand strides.

Comment: If you need *z2* writeable using `broadcast_to` you can `z2.setflags(write=True)`. Perhaps less error-prone than `as_strided`.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny.  Yes, your solution is simpler and much less error prone.  But it scares me in a different way: When something is explicitly documented as being read-only, I really don't know what will happen when I force it to be writeable. I know nothing about how `broadcast_to` is implemented.  It may work in this version of numpy, but not in future versions.

Comment: I tried `y2 = np.broadcast_to(z, (4, 3, 3))`. Both `y2.nbytes` and `z2.nbytes` gave 288. Why is this the case? I was expecting `y2` to consume fewer bytes than `z2` since the former uses views to achieve the duplication. `write=True` was not used.

Comment: @SunBear.  I'm not sure `z2.nbytes` can be trusted when you start playing around with the underlying data structures.  Try `z2 = np.broadcast_to(z, (1_000_000_000, 3, 3))` and see if you can see any change in the amount of memory used by your program.

Comment: I have checked. Appended my findings to my question. I wonder what is the purpose of `nbytes` given that `np.broadcast_to()` is significantly faster than `np.repeat()` and yet both returned the same amount of nbytes?

Comment: nbytes is confused and returning the wrong result.  One is allocating a big array and the other is putting a new header on the already allocated array.

Answer (score 0):

**`numpy.repeat` creates a new array** and not a view (you can check it by looking the `__array_interface__` field). In fact, it is *not possible to create a view on the original array* **in the general case** *since Numpy views does not support such pattern*. A views is basically just an object containing a pointer to a raw memory buffer, some strides, a shape and a type. While it is possible to repeat one item N times with a 0 stride, it is not possible to repeat 2 items N times (without adding a new dimension to the output array). Thus, no there is no way to build a function like `numpy.repeat` having the *same* array output shape to repeat items of the last axis. If adding a *new dimension* is Ok, then you can build an array with a new dimension and a stride set to 0. Repeating the last dimension is possible though. The answer of @FrankYellin gives a good example. Note that reshaping/ravel the resulting array cause a mandatory *copy*. Supporting such advanced views would make the Numpy code more complex or/and less efficient for a feature that is only used rarely by users.